# Laravel 5.7: Get the file size depends on the extension of each folder

Tags: laravel, file, laravel-5, file-upload, laravel-5.7

In our application, we implemented the file upload for each module. What we have done right now is the file will save depends on the module.

**Example we have 3 modules:**

`1) Module A 
2) Module B 
3) Module C`

when the user uploaded a file in Module A. It will look like this

```
// Assuming your company id is 11

public/attachments/11/Module A/filename.fileextension
```

If user uploaded another file in Module B

```
// Company id is still 11

public/attachments/11/Module B/filename.fileextension
```

NOTE: It can have a multiple file extension of each Module.

EXAMPLE: Inside of this public/attachments/11/Module A/. There's a file xxx.jpg, xxx.docx, xxx.pdf

Now this is what we want, we want to get the total size of each extension then display it in our view

**Example**

```
Attachment Uploaded Size:
Images: 900 KB
Docs/x: 250 MB
PDF: 100 KB
```

**Controller**

```
/* =========================== GET ALL UPLOADED FILES =========================== */


        $all_attachments                    = CustomerModel::getAllAttachments();
        if($all_attachments)
        {
            $docs_size = 0;
            foreach($all_attachments as $key => $file)
            {
                /* === FILE NAME === */
                $filename   = $file->filename;

                /* === FILE EXTENSION === */
                $extension  = \File::extension($filename);


                if($extension == 'docx' || $extension == 'doc')
                {
                    // dd("sss");
                    $docs_size += $file->size();
                }
                // dd($foo);
                // $file =
                // dd($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
            }

        }
```

**Attachment Files table**

```
ID
Module Type(string)
File name(string)
```

Question: Is it possible to sum all the same file extension?

Comment: Example in Module A, it can have multiple extension. xxx.jpg, xxx.pdf, xxx.docs

Comment: Laravel uses **Filesystem** in management of **File**. I think there no simple way you can achieve that. Well here is a list of methods you can use https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/usage/filesystem-api/ and the actual file is stored inside `...\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php` hope that will help.

Comment: Have you tried the \File::files() ?